# How to increment each string element from one array that is found in another array?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've kind of stuck on this problem, the goal is to find matching values from column A in column B and increment same values by 1 only in column B, this goes for single aswell as many character strings. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks! This is what I tried:

```
function compareValuesAndIncrementByOne(){
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  
  var range = sh.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  var headers = values.shift();
  
  var array_1 = [];
  var array_2 = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    
    array_1.push([values[i][0]]);
    array_2.push([values[i][1]]);    
    
    array_2[i].join().split(',');
    
  }
  try{
  for (var i = 0; i < array_1.length; i++){
    if (array_1[i].includes(array_2[i])){
      var index = array_2[i].findIndex(array_1[i]);
      array_2[index] = parseInt(array_1[i])+1;
    }
  }}catch(e){Logger.log(e)}
  Logger.log(array_2);
}
```

Here is the link to the spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u55xVnGrZfaHedB1UwhQpcuxmtVtkWi-LxDHtU30CwQ/edit?usp=sharing

Desired Result Screenshot[image]

#### Problem:

When loging the `arr_2`, values are `"1", "2", "1,2,3", "3"`, but they should actually be `"2", "3", "2,3,4", "4"`

Comment: Where is the error, which part of the code does not work?

Comment: When loging the arr_2, values "1", "2", "1,2,3", "3" should actually be "2", "3", "2,3,4", "4"

Comment: If your shared Spreadsheet is the situation before you run the script, can I ask you about the detail of expected situation after you run the script?

Comment: Ofcourse, expected situation would be like in column C, getting every number from array_2, which matches with the number from array_1 column, incremented by 1.

Comment: @prkos  Questions should be 1. Self-contained: not depend on external links- Consider adding a screenshot of your sheet. 2. Have a clear problem statement and debugging details. See [mcve] Kindly [edit] your question. If you do, reply back and I'll add a answer.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @TheMaster I have uploaded the screenshot, idea was to compare each number from array_1 to all the numbers from array_2 if match is found increment only matches in array_2.

Comment: Yes. But that's not the problem. That is your goal. Add debugging details.  You should add this comment:`When loging the arr_2, values "1", "2", "1,2,3", "3" should actually be "2", "3", "2,3,4", "4"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [recursion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Recursion):

```js
const array_1 = [[1], [2], [3]], //simulate array_1 and 2
  array_2 = [[1], [5], [3], ['1,3,2,4']];
const array_1_flat = array_1.flat(); //flatten array to use includes
const increment = arg =>
  Array.isArray(arg) //if the arg is a array, recurse each element with map
    ? arg.map(increment)
    : String(arg).includes(',') //if arg includes "," , split and recurse
    ? arg
        .split(',')
        .map(e => increment(parseInt(e)))
        .join()
    : array_1_flat.includes(arg) //if arg is present in array_1
    ? arg + 1
    : arg;
console.log(array_2.map(increment));
```

Comment: This is greatly appreciated and exactly what I wanted to achieve! Big thanks, apologies for a bit unclear question, but this was my first post. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right your question you want a function that takes the values in column B and adds +1 to them no matter if they are of type number or a string of the form `1,2,3` , i.e a string of numbers separated by commas.

The following piece of code with explanatory comments achieves this purpose. The image below is a demonstration of this.

```js
function compareValuesAndIncrementByOne(){
  // Get our sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Data');
  
  // Get the range of column B with all the values we need to increment. As getValues()
  // return a 2D array we flat it to ease the manipullation of it
  var valuesRangeB = sheet.getRange(2,2,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues().flat();
  
  // for all the rows of the column
  for(i=0;i<valuesRangeB.length;i++){
    // if the row is not empty
    if(valuesRangeB[i]!==''){
      // if the row values is not a string, i.e it is a number we simply need to add 1
      // to the value obtained by get values
      if(valuesRangeB[i].length == null){
        sheet.getRange(i+2, 4).setValue(valuesRangeB[i]+1);
        // else in our case it would be a string such as 1,2,3
      }else{
        // convert string to an array by splitting it by commas. "1,2,3" would then be
        // [1,2,3] array object. Then map all its elements to add 1 to each of the elements
        // of the array we got from the string and convert it back to a string which will 
        // automatically add the commas back 
        var arr = valuesRangeB[i].split(",");
        arr = arr.map(function(val){return ++val;});
        sheet.getRange(i+2, 4).setValue(arr.toString());
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mateo it is very helpful and well explained, however idea was to only increment matches, lets say that there is number 6 in array_2 that one shouldn't be incremented.